# How to display a non-breaking space with VB's inline XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am using VB9's inline XML, and I have a need to specify a non-breaking space. Where you would normally use "`&nbsp;`" in html, using it in inline XML produces the "XML entity references are not supported" error. How do you specify a non-breaking space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most named entities are not supported in XML unless you explicitly declare them in a DTD.  You can, however, use the unicode entity & #160; (without the space, of course).

[This](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) is a good site for looking up unicode characters.